# Xamarin Cross Platform - Image files from IPhotoPickerService not appearing

Tags: android, xamarin

[How to create a image picker on Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002371/how-to-create-a-image-picker-on-xamarin-forms)

This worked, managed to stream the file to the app directory 'files' from any device folder.

But when picking an image file from the Camera folder the image file does not appear in the image tag.
The images from all other folders do appear. Any ideas?

...

```
        Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync();
        if (stream != null)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), thewordsetid.ToString());
            FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePathName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            stream.Position = 0;
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Close();
        }



public class PhotoPickerService : IPhotoPickerService
{
    public Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync()
    {
        // Define the Intent for getting images
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetType("image/*");
        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);

        // Start the picture-picker activity (resumes in MainActivity.cs)
        MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(
            Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Photo"),
            MainActivity.PickImageId);

        // Save the TaskCompletionSource object as a MainActivity property
        MainActivity.Instance.PickImageTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();

        // Return Task object
        return MainActivity.Instance.PickImageTaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check your Output Window. It caused by the too large image.

```
Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3120x4160, max=4096x4096)
```

The photo which match the max size(4096x4096) would be loaded. You could check the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: From this post I found how to resize it

Answer (score 0):

From this post I found how to resize it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56040512/8325235

...

```
        MediaFile photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions { 
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight, MaxWidthHeight = 4096,
                DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear,
                Directory = "files",
                SaveToAlbum = true
        });

        File.Copy(photo.Path, filePathName);
```

...