# How can I resize and compress an image file in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am building a mobile app with Xamarin. I am trying to add a feature where the user can select a photo from their library and I send it via a REST API to an online service. This API only allows .jpg, .jpeg and .png and has a size limit of 2MB. The issue here is that the pictures from the library are bigger than that and in .HEIC.

The steps I want to take to fix this are:

1. Resize the picture so that the height and width don't exceed 1500px. Extra resolution would be useless anyway.
2. Convert the file to .jpg image.

I cannot find how to do step 1. I found some results online but those refer to paying services or to the System.Drawing that doesn't work with Xamarin.

Also, my plan for step 2 is to try to set the quality setting to 100% (if I find a tool that allows such a thing). And then check if the size is below 2MB and if not, re-compress the original file with 5% less quality. All this in a loop to make sure that I get the highest quality possible. Is that a bad idea? Is there a better way?

I know that I can give some quality parameters to the PickPhotoAsync(), but I still wouldn't be sure that the size doesn't exceed 2MB and I also don't want to compress files that already are small enough.

Comment: there are dozens of existing questions like this - none of them were helpful?  Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750272/how-to-resize-images-in-xamarin-forms?

Comment: @Jason: A lot of the "resize image xamarin" results I got were about displaying images. The link you provided does help though, thanks!